# How to create an array of identical elements and give them different styles in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am using **.find()** to identify a repeating element and give each one of them different background colours. What I want is :

1. Create an array (colour array) of colours manually(#EF4128,#BA1028, #2C4534 etc)
2. Find all the h3 with "widget-title" class and put them into an array (element array)
3. Give each item a different colour with matching both the arrays.

It should be a simple job for many here. However I did the following since I am not familiar with while loops and things. Could anyone please tell me how to make this short and sweet?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){        
var item1 = jQuery('h3.widget-title')[0];
var item2 = jQuery('h3.widget-title')[1];
var item3 = jQuery('h3.widget-title')[2];
var item4 = jQuery('h3.widget-title')[3];
var item5 = jQuery('h3.widget-title')[4];
var item6 = jQuery('h3.widget-title')[5];
var item7 = jQuery('h3.widget-title')[6];

jQuery('aside').find( item1 ).css('background-color', '#5938A2');
jQuery('aside').find( item2 ).css('background-color', '#BE8A45');
jQuery('aside').find( item3 ).css('background-color', '#B6AE18');
jQuery('aside').find( item4 ).css('background-color', '#864D75');
jQuery('aside').find( item5 ).css('background-color', '#2C4534');
jQuery('aside').find( item6 ).css('background-color', '#BA1028');
jQuery('aside').find( item7 ).css('background-color', '#EF4128');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would reduce your code like so

```
$(function(){        
    var colours = ['#5938A2', '#BE8A45', '#B6AE18', '#864D75', '#2C4534', 
                   '#BA1028', '#EF4128'];

    $('aside h3.widget-title').each(function(i) {
        $(this).css('background-color', colours[i] || "#000");
        /* if you have more elements than colours defined, use 
         * a default colour - e.g. #000
         */
    });
});
```

the index of current element is passed inside the `each()` method and it is used for a simple array lookup

---

if all those headings are siblings, a different solution involving more CSS and modern browsers could be achieved defining several CSS rules like so

```
h3.widget-title.changecolour { background-color: #5938A2; }
h3.widget-title.changecolour ~ h3.widget-title { background-color: #BE8A45; }
...
h3.widget-title.changecolour ~ ... ~ h3.widget-title { background-color: #EF4128; }
```

and then simply add a `changecolour` class to the first `h3.widget-title` element. This will automatically change the background color of every other sibling headings

Comment: Even better would be using the `each(function(index, value)){ // use the value variable }` function, so the code would be more readable.

Comment: Thank you @Fabrizio for the guidance! I have implemented it and it works fantastic! 

I didn't know about the CSS thing! I am still much of CSS2 high time for me to upgrade myself on CSS! Please visit the site and see for yourself, your code in action! [kalavilasa](http://kalavilasa.com)

Thank you everyone else who helped me here!